# Bitcoin ZeroMQ and Scala application

Tags: java, zeromq

I'm trying to connect to Bitcoin's ZeroMQ queue, having no success and don't even know where my problem is. Here is what I did so far on my Ubuntu 14.04:

1. Installed Bitcoin via `sudo apt-get install bitcoin-qt`
2. installed ZeroMQ via `wget http://download.zeromq.org/zeromq-4.1.2.tar.gz && cd libzmq/ && ./autogen.sh && ./configure && make -j 4 && make check && make install`
3. In my Scala application I use `jeromq`: `libraryDependencies += "org.zeromq" % "jeromq" % "0.3.5"`
4. In Bitcoin's `bitcoin.conf` I add the following line: `zmqpubhashtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332` (i'm only interested in incoming tx id's)

After doing all that I launch Bitcoin, then I launch my Scala app with the following code:

```
import org.zeromq.ZMQ
val context = ZMQ.context(1)
val socket = context.socket(ZMQ.SUB) // Since server side is PUB
socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:28332")

while (true) {
  logger info socket.recv.length.toString
}
```

And I receive no messages. Thing is I don't even know what the problem is or how to test it. Does `apt-get` version of Bitcoin even has ZeroMQ support? On `jeromq` github it is stated that it's `Based on libzmq 3.2.5` while Bitcoin requires `ZeroMQ API version 4.x or newer`, could that be a reason? Or perhaps it's something else entirely?

Answer (score 2):

It is not specified what to subscribe.

```
socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:28332")

socket.subscribe("hashtx");
# if you need raw data or block data, to add->
socket.subscribe("hashblock");
socket.subscribe("rawblock");
socket.subscribe("rawtx");
```

see.
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/contrib/zmq/zmq_sub.py